# What is the best way to store software documentation?

Tags: documentation

An obvious answer is "an internal wiki". What are the pros and cons of a wiki used for software documentation? Any other suggestions? What are you using for your software documentation?

[Loren Segal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436/loren-segal) - Unfortunately we don't have support for any doc tool to compile information from the source code comments but I agree it would be the best way to store technical documentation. My question was about every kind of documentation tho - from sysadmin type to user documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a very open ended question, and depends on many factors.

Generally speaking, if you use a language that has good documentation generation tools (javadoc, doxygen, MS's C# stuff), you should write your documentation above your methods and have your tools generate the pages. The advantage is that you keep the *source* of your text alongside your code which means it is orgnanized in the logically correct place and easily editable when you make a change to the behaviour of the method.

If you don't have good doc tool support or don't have access to source code, wiki's aren't a bad idea, but they're a second choice to the above.

Note: I'm talking only about code documentation here. Other artifacts obviously cannot be stored alongside code-- a wiki is a great place to put those documents. Alternatively if you use some CMS you can simply commit them in some `docs/` folder as text/pdf/whatever files to be editable via the repository. The advantage there is that they stay with the repository if it is moved whereas a wiki does not (necessarily).

Answer (score 3):

Tools are important, but don't get too bogged down in finding the magic tool.  No tool I've found yet has a "document everything magically using tiny invisible elves" tickbox.  :-)

A wiki will work fine.  Or Sharepoint.  Or Google docs.  Or you could use a SVN repository.  Hell you could do it with pens, notepaper, and a file cabinets if you really really had to.  (I really don't recommend that!)

The big important key is you need to have buy-in throughout the organization.  What happens in a lot of shops is they go and spend a bunch of time and money on some fancy solution like Sharepoint, and then everyone uses it religiously for about two weeks, and then people get busy with hitting the latest milestone and that's the last anyone hears about it.

Depending on your organization, field, the type of products your developing, etc., there are a few solutions to that, but one way or another you need to set up a system and **use** it.  Appoint someone the official documentation czar, give them a cluebat, and tell them to hit people in the head everytime they say "oh yeah, I'll finish documenting that next week...".  if that's what it takes.  :-)

As for tools...  I'd recommend [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) by Atlassian.  It's a fine wiki, it's designed to work in an enterprise environment, it has a lot of nifty features, it's customizable, it integrates well with some of the Atlassian's other nifty tools, and is basically a pretty solid product.

Answer (score 2):

«Software documentation» is a very general  term. There is «End User documentation», «Developer documentation», «QA Documentation». First one is usually developed by qualified techwriters. Other ones may be dynamically formed from wikis, documentation comments from source code etc. All this stuff maintenance process usually is very complex and each software company follow its own way. But there is one necessary point for all these ways: each code commiter, architect, manager, qa engineer MUST store well arranged each piece of information which may be helpful for the others. And someone else MUST keep an eye on this pieces storage and rearrange pieces if required. All this steps **greatly** improve all activities related to development process.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about code documentation versus user documentation, an internal wiki is great if you do not need to distribute the documentation for the code outside of your organization, to contractors or partners.

Javadoc or DOxygen is more suitable if you want distributable code documentation.

If you are referring to user documentation, you may want to have a look at [DITA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture).

Answer (score 1):

We currently use inline documentation parsed by an external application (PHP + PhpDocumenter) plus various internal wikis. At times it's painful at best (mainly because only one person update the wikis or the docs...)

However, I've been looking at using [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/tips/integrated_issue_tracking_with_ikiwiki/) to do internal docs. It integrate with your source countrol system (including Git, Subversion, Mercurial, Bazaar, TLA and Monotone) so all your docs track with your project. It is built in Perl and has an extensive plugin system (including multiple markup languages, with the default being Markdown). Also, the source control system is plugin based, so if what you use isn't immediately supported you could add your own. In your preferred language, if need be, since it supports non-perl plugins, too.

Comment: Thanks for the ikiwiki link, checking it out now. Have you seen Trac Wiki? [link](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWiki)

Answer (score 1):

I started experimenting with a way to do user documentation with these goals:

**Markdown/Html/Javascript/file-based relatively linked documents** for portability (*can run on local file system or you can throw it on a webserver*), built-in handling of screenshots (*interactively resize*), and open source in case anyone else may want to do something with the crazy thing.

Your document source is written in Markdown and rendered to Html via Javascript at browser runtime.

> [Mandown](http://wittman.org/mandown/)  -  http://wittman.org/mandown/

Comment: Hey, nifty tool.  Incidentally, have you looked at Xilize?  Somewhat similar concept, although very different implementation.

http://xilize.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

My company uses a variety of Sharepoint and a wiki. Sharepoint for specific documents like  requirements, presentations, contracts, etc, while the wiki is used as a help guide a developer repository for tutorials on using internally developed libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, we use a wiki, we also use Google documents. I find that Google documents is better than most wikis I've tried and, if you don't need to track all changes, you lose nothing. Google docs provides a good collaboration framework.