# Using Swagger to Document Methods that are NOT Endpoints

Tags: swagger, documentation-generation

Swagger does a great job of documenting endpoints. But what if I want to auto-generate documentation for classes/class methods that are not endpoints?

1. Is there a way to get Swagger to do this (short of modifying the source)?
2. Are there any solutions out there that do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [What's the equivalent of Swagger for SDKs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46668786/113116)

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the question.

Que:- 1. Is there a way to get Swagger to do this (short of modifying the source)?
ANS:- No, swagger can not modify your source code or add doc. for other classes.

Que:- 2. Are there any solutions out there that do this?
ANS:- Yes, you can use different language documentation processes to generate code documentation. you can check first comment of the question or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668786/whats-the-equivalent-of-swagger-for-sdks)