# How to configure swagger on a class library in .net?

Tags: .net, swagger, portable-class-library, swashbuckle

I have `Class library` project. I want to configure `Swagger` in `Class library` project. I already know how to configure `Swagger` in `.net core` and `web api` but not getting any right way to configure in `Class library` project. If anyone have any idea about it then please share.

Comment: Is this class library intended to be used in a REST API?

Comment: @Helen Actually it is old project and they have used class library.

Comment: OpenAPI Specification and Swagger tools are only for REST APIs, not for generic class libraries. See [What's the equivalent of Swagger for SDKs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46668786/113116)